Paint over this rust?
Is there a relatively easy way to remove this superficial rust from this ceiling fan?
Although I prefer to just stop the actual rusting, and I was thinking of just painting over it with some rust eliminator black enamel paint.
This will go in a small room, so if I do paint it, I'm the only one that will see how ugly it is (ie. it doesn't have to look pretty).



Also Painting rusty metal and lots of other similar questions.

I'd also suggest that fans without rust can be found regularly at garage sales, etc. I'm not sure this is worth your effort.

Will you be able to stop moisture and high humidity from reaching the fan in the future?
